# Public API call working on Mozilla but not on Chrome (react-app)

Tags: reactjs, api, google-chrome, web-deployment, mozilla

I recently tried to deploy my first react-app on to the web. The website is about looking up details for a certain pokemon and making your own card if you like.

I use Mozilla as my main browser and everything works pretty good. But when I ask for a pokemon request (GET) on chrome I don't get any results. If I have a look at the network console I get a 301 Error (from disk cache). What does this mean? You can look at my website at:

https://daan.boschmans.mtantwerp.eu/

I deployed my app using the `npm run build` command.
I added the .htaccess file in the public folder with the proper lines.

GET REQUEST:

```
export const getPokemonSprites = (name) => {
    return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/${name}`).then((response) => {
        if(response.statusText === 'OK') {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    })
}
export const getPokemonMoves = (name) => {
    return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`).then((response) => {
        if(response.statusText === 'OK') {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    })
}
```

This I how I handle the GET call:

```
 getPokeData() {

        if (this.state.searchValue && this.state.name !== this.state.searchValue) {

            this.setState({ isLoading: true, hasError: false, name: "", sprites: [], moves: [], height: "", weight:"", specials: [], base_experience: "", type: [], stats:[], items: [], });

            Promise.all([ getPokemonSprites(this.state.searchValue),getPokemonMoves(this.state.searchValue)])

                .then( ([spriteList, pokeDetails]) => {

                    const sprites   = Object.values(spriteList.sprites);
                    const moves     = Object.entries(pokeDetails.moves);
                    const abilities = Object.entries(pokeDetails.abilities);
                    const types     = Object.entries(pokeDetails.types);
                    const stats     = Object.entries(pokeDetails.stats);


                    for (const [ , value] of Object.entries(moves)) {

                        this.state.moves.push(value[1].move.name);
                    }

                    for (const [, value] of Object.entries(types)) {

                        this.state.type.push(value[1].type.name);

                    }

                    for (const [, value] of Object.entries(abilities)) {

                        this.state.specials.push(value[1].ability.name);

                    }

                    for (const [, value] of Object.entries(stats)) {

                            let statsValue = `${value[1].stat.name}: ${value[1].base_stat}`;

                            this.state.stats.push(statsValue);
                    }

                    this.setState({sprites, name: spriteList.name,  height: pokeDetails.height, weight: pokeDetails.weight, base_experience: pokeDetails.base_experience })

                    }).then(() => { this.setState({isLoading: false, searchValue: ""})})
                      .catch(() => { this.setState({isLoading: false, searchValue: "", hasError: true}) })

        }
    }
```

Any tips would be really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, nice site. Looks like a fun little project.

I tried the website on Chrome and it works fine for me.

Looks as though you have a service worker that is caching content. If you used create-react-app, it comes with a service worker built it and looks as though it is caching the content of your API calls in your browser.

I suspect there is an issue with your Chrome's cache. You could try clearing the cache by following this suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467842/how-to-clear-cache-of-service-worker) or alternatively it may be worth trying to reinstall chrome.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty suprised that it works for you to be honest, I asked a few of my friends to try the get request on chrome and they all get the error I'm having. Did you search for a pokemon and got the results?

Comment: Just added screenshot of it working for me in Chrome. If it helps, I'm running `Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: Okay thanks, This is weird tho. I did reinstall my chrome and tried to remove the cache from the service worker but it's still not working. Any more advice?

Comment: Do you need the service worker? You can remove it if you comment out the import from your `src/index.js` file

Comment: I figured out that I can't use  `Response.statusText === "OK"` for chrome. I  applied some changes and now it works.