# How to delete service worker caches using urls

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

I have this service worker file (`sw.js`) which I got from the internet:

```
const PRECACHE = 'precache-v1.1';
const RUNTIME = 'runtime';

// A list of local resources we always want to be cached.
const PRECACHE_URLS = [

  /* index page */
  'index.html', './',

  /* stylesheets */
  './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', './assets/css/style.css', 

  /* javascripts */
  './assets/js/scripts.js', 

  /* images */
  './assets/images/logo.png'

];

// The install handler takes care of precaching the resources we always need.
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(PRECACHE)
      .then(cache => cache.addAll(PRECACHE_URLS))
      .then(self.skipWaiting())
  );
});

// The activate handler takes care of cleaning up old caches.
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  const currentCaches = [PRECACHE, RUNTIME];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return cacheNames.filter(cacheName => !currentCaches.includes(cacheName));
    }).then(cachesToDelete => {
      return Promise.all(cachesToDelete.map(cacheToDelete => {
        return caches.delete(cacheToDelete);
      }));
    }).then(() => self.clients.claim())
  );
});

// The fetch handler serves responses for same-origin resources from a cache.
// If no response is found, it populates the runtime cache with the response
// from the network before returning it to the page.
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Skip cross-origin requests, like those for Google Analytics.
  if (event.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(cachedResponse => {
        if (cachedResponse) {
          return cachedResponse;
        }

        return caches.open(RUNTIME).then(cache => {
          return fetch(event.request).then(response => {
            // Put a copy of the response in the runtime cache.
            return cache.put(event.request, response.clone()).then(() => {
              return response;
            });
          });
        });
      })
    );
  }
});
```

On every page of my website, say `index.html`, `about.html`, `contact.html`, I have this code:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) { navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js'); }
```

The reason why I have this code on every page is because I have a lot of pages on my website and that I want the browser to cache all the files if the  user lands on any page of my website.

Now for example, when a user visits `about.html`, the service worker caches all the files listed in `sw.js` and also caches the current page even though it's not listed in `sw.js`. This is exactly what I want since I have hundreds of pages on my website and I don't want to manually list all of them in the `sw.js` file. The problem is, when I update the version number in the `sw.js`, the browser deletes all the old caches which are listed in `sw.js` and re-caches the files again, except `about.html`. Whenever the user visits this page again, the old `about.html` gets displayed and all the other files are new.

How can I overcome this issue? I want to delete absolutely all the files cached by my website and not just the files listed in `sw.js` and since `about.html` is not listed, this cached page doesn't get updated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467842/how-to-clear-cache-of-service-worker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your about.html file is saved in the cache named *runtime* which is not versioned. So this cache is still the same, even you deploy a new sw.js with an incremented *PRECACHE*-cache. (e.g precache-v1.2)

The solution is to add versioning to the *runtime*-cache as well:

```
const PRECACHE = 'precache-v1.1';
const RUNTIME = 'runtime-v1.1';
```

Or cleaning the runtime cache on activate:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
// only PRECACHE (which is already the new version, setup on install event) should not be deleted.
const currentCaches = [PRECACHE];
...
```