# Clearing Cache in PWA

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I want to develop an offline capable progressive web application.

Looking into an example of such an app - airhorner I find that it uses specific version of the application to make sure correct version is loaded.

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/airhorn/blob/main/app/sw.js#L21

However what happens with older version? Do I need to cleanup it? My app is rather large because it contains lots of data (html+js ~1.5MB) and from what I read on iOS there is limit of 50MB of cache per app.

So I wonder if I need to make sure I remove cache of older versions or I can just assume it is cache and it will be removed because it is too old?

if I do need to remove older version, where is the correct place to call it?

I see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45468998/66522 that it is called for `activate` event. Can I just add another event listener on this event in addition to this one? https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/airhorn/blob/main/app/sw.js#L40

Answer (score 1):

A cache is volatile. The browser may choose to delete everything, or nothing, at any given time. (Ref: [Deleting cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#deleting_old_caches))

That being said, it's common practice to clean up after yourself. This becomes especially important when you have a limitation on 50Mb; You don't want the browser to automatically clear a valid cache.

You should do any kind of cleanup in the `activate` event, so that any old and active ServiceWorkers will still be able to function until the new ServiceWorker has claimed all clients (Become active).

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache#examples)'s an example of how to manage cache in a ServiceWorker.